# How to feed the model with a stack of images instead of one by one?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

I built a 2D model, but the dataset contains a group of images from different viewpoints for each patient, so the input should be a stack of images for each patient.

[image]

I have compressed each group of images in nii.gz format:

```
mport SimpleITK as sitk
import glob

file_names = sorted(glob.glob('/path/to/dataset/patient/*.png'))
reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()
reader.SetFileNames(file_names)
vol = reader.Execute()
sitk.WriteImage(vol, '/path/to/dataset/patient/2639.nii.gz')
```

I don't know now how to use these compressed images to feed the model.
Kindly help me, if someone can guide me.